# Does two minimum of a continous function imply at least one maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Can we prove that for a continous function (not necessarily smooth), if it has two local minimum in the confined domain, then it must has at least one local maximum.

This seems to be obvious for one dimensional function, but not for multivariable functions.

Comment: consider $(x, y) \mapsto x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider function $f(x,y) = sin(x) + y^{2}$. It has infinitely many local minimums and no local maximum. Intuitively (that is geometrically) it is easily to see why - at any point where $sin(x) = 1$ and $y = 0$ we have a saddle i.e. along x-axis the graph looks like we have a local maximum at the point and, at the same time along y-axis it looks like local minimum.
At the same time each point where $sin(x) = -1$ and $y=0$ we have local minimum.
One can confirm this by computing derivatives of course.